# can anyone explain this combinatorial problem?

Tags: combinatorics

I got this problem from "$102$ Combinatorial Problems From the Training of USA IMO Team". I don't need the solution to this problem. Just an explanation of what I'm supposed to prove.

Let $n$ be an odd integer greater than 1. Prove that the sequence 
$${\binom{n}{1}},{\binom{n}{2}},..,{\binom{n}{(n-1)/2}}$$ contains an odd number of odd numbers.

I don't understand what they meant by "Odd number of odd numbers".

**DON'T GIVE ME THE SOLUTION. ONLY. ONLY AN EXPLANATION.**

Comment: I suppose they mean an odd number of terms in the product are odd, but that is just a guess.

Comment: Oh sorry i made a mistake, let me correct it.

Comment: @SBareS I don't really understand What you just said. Explain it, please.

Comment: The number of odd elements in the sequence is in itself a number. The statement just says that this number is odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s an example to show you how it works : consider $n=19$. 
We have the following nine numbers :

$$
\binom{n}{1}=19,
\binom{n}{2}=171,
\binom{n}{3}=969,
\binom{n}{4}=3876,
\binom{n}{5}=11628,
\binom{n}{6}=27132,
\binom{n}{7}=50388,
\binom{n}{8}=75582,
\binom{n}{9}=92378,
$$

The odd numbers in the sequence above are :

$$
\binom{n}{1}=19,
\binom{n}{2}=171,
\binom{n}{3}=969
$$

There are three of them, and the number three is odd. This is what is meant by
"an odd number of odd numbers".

Answer (score 2):

You have a sequence consisting of the $\frac{n-1}2$ numbers $\binom{n}1$, $\binom{n}2$, and so on up through $\binom{n}{(n-1)/2}$. These numbers are all integers, so some of them are odd numbers, and some are even. Say that $a$ of them are odd; then $a$ is an integer between $0$ and $\frac{n-1}2$ inclusive, and you’re to prove that $a$ is an odd number.

Answer (score 1):

Exemple with $n=9$

The green sequence from Pascal's triangle $$1,\color{green}{9,36,84,126},126,84,36,9,1$$ contains exactly $1$ odd value. $1$ is odd.